# Outlook 2016 VSTO-Addin: How to avoid System.AccessVioloationExceptionfor "outdated" link to AppointmentItem?

Tags: outlook-addin

As you can see I checked for appointmentItem != null and rtfBody.Length != 0 
although the call to appointmentItem.GetInspector throws a System.AccessVioloationException.
This happens when I run my Outlook addon via VisualStudio for a longer time (several hours) and then close Outlook.
My idea is that this is caused by the fact that Outlook is already shutting down, thus the AppointmentItem still exists but some COM related things are out of order. But this is only a vague guess.
Do you have any idea why this happens and how to avoid this?

Furthermore I already added a try/catch like:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
   log.Info(ex.Message);
   return 0;
}
```

But the exception does not get caught. So I need to additionally catch SystemExceptions explicitly I understand, right?

[image: s]

Answer (score 0):

> This happens when I run my Outlook addon via VisualStudio for a longer time (several hours) and then close Outlook.

The common language runtime exposes COM objects through a proxy called the runtime callable wrapper (RCW). Although the RCW appears to be an ordinary object to .NET clients, its primary function is to marshal calls between a .NET client and a COM object. So, if the COM server doesn't exist (Outlook is closed) your calls to the RCW don't make any sense.

By default, starting from .NET 4.0, the common language runtime (CLR) does not deliver these exceptions to managed code, and the try/catch blocks (and other exception-handling clauses) are not invoked for them. If you are absolutely sure that you want to maintain your handling of these exceptions, you must apply the `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute` attribute to the method whose exception-handling clauses you want to execute. The CLR delivers the corrupted process state exception to applicable exception clauses only in methods that have both the `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute` and `SecurityCriticalAttribute` attributes.

You can also add the `<legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy>` element to your application's configuration file. This will ensure that corrupted state exceptions are delivered to your exception handlers without the `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute` or `SecurityCriticalAttribute` attribute. This configuration element has no effect on applications that were compiled in versions previous to the .NET Framework 4 but are running in the .NET Framework 4 or later; corrupted state exceptions will continue to be delivered for those applications. The `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute` attribute is ignored when it is encountered in partially trusted or transparent code, because a trusted host should not allow an untrusted add-in to catch and ignore these serious exceptions.

For more information about corrupted process state exceptions, see the entry [Handling Corrupted State Exceptions](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=179681) in the CLR Inside blog.

You can also handle the following events of the `AppDomain` class:

- [AppDomain.UnhandledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception?view=netcore-3.1) is fired when an exception is not caught. Starting with the .NET Framework 4, this event is not raised for exceptions that corrupt the state of the process, such as stack overflows or access violations, unless the event handler is security-critical and has the `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute` attribute.
- [AppDomain.FirstChanceException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception?view=netcore-3.1) is fired when an exception is thrown in managed code, before the runtime searches the call stack for an exception handler in the application domain.